# Logitech webcam with Beaglebone Black and opencv. It works a few times then I get errors

Tags: c++, image, opencv, beagleboneblack

I have a Beaglebone Black (Ångström distribution) with a Logitech webcam connected to it. It has been working fine so far, but sometimes it does not. I have a program that takes a few pictures (I save it in a Mat object) and then it goes through some processes. Whenever it works fine I get this:

```
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
It works... processing...
```

As I mentioned, despite of the message of `Invalid argument`, it works. The problem is that after running my program a few times I get this instead:

```
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Input/output error
HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable to ioctl S_FMT
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Input/output error
libv4l1: error setting pixformat: Input/output error
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Input/output error
libv4l1: error setting pixformat: Input/output error
HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable to ioctl VIDIOCSPICT

Error: webcam connection
Failed to capture an image
```

So I get a few less `Invalid argument` messages and those errors. These last two messages come from my function:

```
void takePicture()
{
  VideoCapture capture(0);
  capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1920);
  capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,1080);

  // This is done because of some focus problems I've been having
  for(int i=0; i < 20; i++)
  {
    capture >> image;
  }

  if (!capture.isOpened())
    cout << "Error: webcam connection" << endl;

  // This is done because of some focus problems I've been having
  for(int i=0; i < 20; i++)
  {
    capture >> image;
  }

  if(image.empty())
    cout << "Failed to capture an image" << endl;

  // Save image
  sprintf(filename2,"qr.jpg");
  imwrite(filename2, image);
}
```

After this, if I try again I will get the same until I reboot the Beaglebone. Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Not all webcams are supported by the linux driver, so you should check if yours is supported or not. http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/

Comment: @fonZ mine is not in that list, but as I say, it does take pictures. Does it mean that anyway it is not supported even if it works? Does it have anything to do with the error I am getting? Thanks!

Comment: it means that your webcam is not supported by the driver. So it might work, but there is a good chance that it doesn't or gives unexpected behavior, as you are experiencing. So you need a good driver, one that supports your webcam.